# Interchange Of Infimum and Integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, interpolation-theory

The following question is in regard to a line from the textbook `Interpolation Spaces' by Bergh and Lofstrom. More precisely, it is in regard to the last line on page 110, in the proof of Theorem 5.2.2.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $0<p_{0}<p_{1}<\infty$, and suppose that $f\in L^{p_{0}}(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)+L^{p_{1}}(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ (these can be either real or complex $L^{p}$ spaces). Bergh and Lofstrom then claim that for any $t>0$ one has that

$$\inf_{\substack{f=f_{0}+f_{1} \\ f_{0}\in L^{p_{0}} \\ f_{1}\in L^{p_{1}} }}\int_{\Omega}|f_{0}(x)|^{p_{0}}+t|f_{1}(x)|^{p_{1}}d\mu(x)=\int_{\Omega}\inf_{\substack{f(x)=f_{0}(x)+f_{1}(x) \\ f_{0}\in L^{p_{0}} \\ f_{1}\in L^{p_{1}} }}\big(|f_{0}(x)|^{p_{0}}+t|f_{1}(x)|^{p_{1}}\big)d\mu(x).$$

So, my question is how does one prove this? Of course, if $f_{0}\in L^{p_{0}}$ and $f_{1}\in L^{p_{1}}$ with $f=f_{0}+f_{1}$ then clearly

$$|f_{0}(x)|^{p_{0}}+t|f_{1}(x)|^{p_{1}}\geq\inf_{\substack{f(x)=f_{0}(x)+f_{1}(x) \\ f_{0}\in L^{p_{0}} \\ f_{1}\in L^{p_{1}} }}\big(|f_{0}(x)|^{p_{0}}+t|f_{1}(x)|^{p_{1}}\big)$$

for all $x\in\Omega$ and so

$$\inf_{\substack{f=f_{0}+f_{1} \\ f_{0}\in L^{p_{0}} \\ f_{1}\in L^{p_{1}} }}\int_{\Omega}|f_{0}(x)|^{p_{0}}+t|f_{1}(x)|^{p_{1}}d\mu(x)\geq\int_{\Omega}\inf_{\substack{f(x)=f_{0}(x)+f_{1}(x) \\ f_{0}\in L^{p_{0}} \\ f_{1}\in L^{p_{1}} }}\big(|f_{0}(x)|^{p_{0}}+t|f_{1}(x)|^{p_{1}}\big)d\mu(x).$$

However, I am stuck trying to prove the reverse inequality. Any help or any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must use a sequence of functions $f^n_0,f^n_1$, with $f^n_0 + f^n_1 = f$ and satisfying $f^n_0 \in L^{p_0}, f^n_1 \in L^{p_1}$, for which the terms $|f^n_0(x)|^{p_0} + t|f^n_{1}(x)|^{p_1}$ converges uniformly to the function $x \to \inf_{f(x) = f_0(x) + f_1(x) , f_0 \in L^{p_0},f_1 \in L^{p_1}} (|f_0(x)|^{p_0} + t|f_1(x)|^{p_1})$. Then the reverse inequality applies to each $n$, and by uniformity you can slide $n$ to infinity. Of course, I could be wrong, but this is what is done usually.